# 'list indices must be integers, not str' after converting string to dictionary

Tags: python, django, elementtree

Using `POST` request i recieve this one respond

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response version="1.1">
   <accommodations>
      <accommodation name="accom1">
         <concepts>
            <concept name="concept1-1">
               <boards>
                  <board name="board1-1">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
                  <board name="board1-2">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
        </concept>
            <concept name="concept2-1">
               <boards>
                  <board name="board2-1">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
                  <board name="board2-2">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
        </boards>
        </concept>
     </concepts>
      </accommodation>
      <accommodation name="accom2">
         <concepts>
            <concept name="concept3-1">
               <boards>
                  <board name="board3-1">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
                  <board name="board3-2">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
        </concept>
            <concept name="concept4-1">
               <boards>
                  <board name="board4-1">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
                  <board name="board4-2">
                     <description>description</description>
                  </board>
        </boards>
        </concept>
     </concepts>
       </accommodation>
    </accommodations>
</response>
```

Here is code of request:

```
my_request = urllib2.Request(url, message)
response_xml = urllib2.urlopen(my_request)
my_response = response_xml.read()
```

Then i convert string to dictionary:

```
def etree_to_dict(t):
        d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
        children = list(t)
        if children:
                dd = defaultdict(list)
                for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
                        for k, v in dc.iteritems():
                                dd[k].append(v)
                d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.iteritems()}}
        if t.attrib:
                d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.iteritems())
        if t.text:
                text = t.text.strip()
                if children or t.attrib:
                        if text:
                                d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
                else:
                        d[t.tag] = text
        return d    
my_result = ET.fromstring(my_response.decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
d = globalvars.etree_to_dict(my_result)
```

Then i try to save some data from dictionary to data base. When i try to save `name="accom1"`, everythig works fine:

```
 my_data=d['response']['accommodations']['accommodation']
        for n in my_data.get('accommodation'):
                p = XMLData(
                        name = n.get('@name')
                )
```

But when i try to save `board` `name`, i've got an error:
`list indices must be integers, not str`

```
 my_data=d['response']['accommodations']['accommodation']['concepts']
    for n in my_data:
            p = XMLData(
                    board = n['@name']
            )
```

I don't get why does it happen. Can you help me with it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `n` is a list of boards. You must use integer list indexes (0,1, etc) to access its elements. `board = n['@name']` must be `board = n[I]` where `O` is an integer number.

Comment: @DYZ thank you for your comment. But if i will use indexes i will have access to elemenst such as `description` but not to `<board name="board1-1">`. Am i  wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. You have a list of two boards; they have their attributes, but list elements cannot be accessed by attributes. You must construct a dictionary for the attribute-based access.